# Keeping cell Text formatting after applying a function

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am going to show a bit of a contrived example, so bear with it.

Our product makes use of CSV files for transitional data, data sent between an Excel user interface, a Java program to manipulate and transfer it to a SQL backend.  We have a VBA script that handles all the Excel work in the following order:

Load all 8 CSV files into 8 sheets in a single Excel document.  Then iterate over batches of the data doing the following:

```
'Loop over data:
    Dim r As Range
    ...
    r.NumberFormat = "General"
    r.Formula = r.Formula
'End loop
```

This causes the entire sheet to be populated with data from CSV, with number cells to have text appearance and Excel formulas to remain unevaluated.  Running r.Formula = r.Formula triggers all the functions to evaluate properly.  The only problem is the number formatting.

The CSV files sometimes contain nested CSV.  For example, a single cell may contain "1,2,3,15,654"  These cells always appear as text.  However, there is an edge case, wherein the cells could be pretty print numbers, such as "10,456,345"  Excel will convert these numbers into Number cells after evaluating all the functions, and strip out all of the commas.  While the 20,000 or so rows in the document are otherwise correct, the 4 or so rows this affects breaks the entire system.

Is there a way to trigger Excel to evaluate the functions from CSV without changing the cell formatting entirely from VBA?  Changing formats from CSV to SYLK is not an option, as the Java CSV Generator is handled by a different division.

Comment: Do you mean that your CSV file contains Excel formulas (as in "=R1C1" or "=A1" for example)?

Comment: Have you tried `r.NumberFormat = "@"` which defines the cell as text?

Comment: @assylias Yes, it contains Excel formulas.  The Java program produces the correct formulas as needed and generates the CSV files with them in the right places.  r.Formulas = r.Formulas triggers them to evaluate.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Yes, and that causes the cells with formulas to not evaluate.  I'd rather not go over each cell one at a time as it drags the macro execution time from ~5 seconds to ~50.  That's why I do it in batches of 500 rows at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn formatting to text on all the cells (Cells.NumberFormat="@") then loop over them and use your code on cells which start with '='.
If performance is an issue you should put the worksheet content in an array, work on the array and put it back to the sheet.
If you post more code and sample data people will be able to have a closer look.

**EDIT**

for example, putting the following values in column A (from A1 to A4) of "Sheet1", with a Text formatting:

```
13246
13564,4654,4565
654
=A1+A3
```

and using the following code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim a As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    a = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    ReDim result(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2)) As Variant

    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
      For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        If Left(a(i, j), 1) = "=" Then
          result(i, j) = a(i, j)
        Else
          result(i, j) = "'" & a(i, j)
        End If
      Next j
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2)) = result

End Sub
```

The result is put in column B and is :

```
13246
13564,4654,4565
654
13900
```

Comment: Pushing it into an array might be more managable.  Is there an upper bounds on array sizes?  I know there is on string lengths.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit imposed by VBA (see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;177991), it will most likely be limited by your memory. You could store millions of numbers without any problems for example.

Comment: I personally try to do as much processing on arrays as possible because I generally work on 100k++ records at a time and it improves performance significantly. So a typical workflow would be: read data from a sheet into an array, process the data and put the result into another array, copy that new array to the destination sheet.

Comment: BTW, if you could post some code and a sample file you could get more specific answers...

Comment: Moving data into an array has been significantly accelerating the work.  The function in question is a "User-friendly formatter" so I am already require to touch entire rows and columns to stylize the elements as needed, but data operations on the cells seems to be working.  I'm not sure though where moving the data into the array is a help here, as I still need to cause the functions to evaluate and keep the cell NumberFormat in tact, both of which are functions of the cell, not the contents.

Comment: Okay seems good.  Although the caveat with this is the pretty print.  I'm not on the dev machine at the moment, but would the second cell still format correctly if you did 21,412,413 ?

Comment: Easy to check - will have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative technique that may be suitable.

I created a worksheet with 26,000 values: strings, numbers, dates, numbers with embedded commas and formulae.

I ran a loop over the above sheet of which the inner code was:

```
     ValueCell = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Formula
     If IsNumeric(Replace(ValueCell, ",", "")) Then
       .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Formula = Replace(ValueCell, ",", "|")
     End If
```

`.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Formula` gives the formula if the cell contains one or the value if it does not.  If the value or formula with any commas removed is numeric, I replace any commas with pipes.

With 26,000 cells this took 59 seconds.  Does this compare favourable with your extra 45 seconds per 500 rows?

Any values like "1,2,3,15,654" would now be "1|2|3|15|654" but I assume that is not a problem.  If you have nested strings such as "ab,cd,ef" they would still contain commas.  Perhaps testing for a leading "=" to eliminate formulae and automatically replacing commas in everything else would be a possibility.

The following code took 78 seconds to run against 26,000 cells.

```
     ValueCell = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Formula
     If Left(ValueCell, 1) <> "=" Then
       .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Formula = Replace(ValueCell, ",", "|")
     End If
```

Hope this helps if only to give you new ideas.

Comment: That is a good solution.  Our total operating time on the whole workbook is 5 seconds, not 5 seconds per 500 rows.  Its quite well optimized except for the numbering problem.  Over a minute will probably not be deliverable.  Using an alternate delimiter is probably acceptable, and I'll see if I can get the other teams to change the comma in the nested CSV to a semicolor or other reasonable typable character.  Or perhaps get the CSV generator / parse only to work with semicolons as nested delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative, more straightforward approach:

Have you considered writing to an Excel spreadsheet directly from your Java program, using e.g. [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)? Seems to me it would be much more straightforward, less contrived, and less error-prone than this whole formulas-in-a-CSV business.

Comment: Yes, I have, but the mandate was no open source tools.  A stupid terrible requirement but a requirement nevertheless.

Comment: Well, as soon as it's compiled, it isn't open source anymore... What an absurd requirement. It's just as absurd as requiring the code to be written without the letter "e" in it.

Comment: The thought is that community driven means no support and no one to assure that there are no vulnerabilities.  My reasoning is that open source is the only way to assure no vulnerabilities, but that's not the management's opinion.  Apparently they want someone to assign blame to if they need.  Using POI libraries falls into that.  MySQL as well, but Oracle is allowed.

Comment: But there is even less support for home-grown dirty hacks written by some employee (a community of one) who might not be working here next year! Let alone any guarantee that there are no vulnerabilities to those hacks. Then why go with the hacks?! Sigh. Management. Let them wallow in their content self-delusion.